# Select average and average by condition

Tags: mysql

In my query, I need to select four values - average, average for certain date, total count, and count for certain date. My query is now only for average and count. Is it needed to have two queries or is it possible to use only one?

```
SELECT AVG(value) as average, 
COUNT(*) as noRates 
FROM `ratings` WHERE mid = 31
```

What I wish is something like

```
SELECT AVG(value) as average, 
COUNT(*) as noRates, 
AVG(value WHERE datecolumn = '2014-10-17') as averageToday, 
COUNT(* WHERE datecolumn = '2014-10-17') as noRatesToday 
FROM `ratings` 
WHERE mid = 31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For conditional average you can use case and for conditional count you can directly put your expression  in sum to behave it like as count function

```
SELECT 
AVG(`value`) AS average, 
COUNT(*) AS noRates,
 AVG( CASE WHEN datecolumn = '2014-10-17' THEN `value` ELSE 0 END) AS averageToday,
 SUM(datecolumn = '2014-10-17') AS noRatesToday 
 FROM `ratings` 
 WHERE `mid` = 31
```

Comment: Thanks for respond, but this is not working. I created mid 30 with random values and only today in datecolumn, but averageToday and noRatesToday returning zeros. Values had to be same like average and noRates which works fine.

Comment: `AVG(CASE WHEN datecolumn = '2014-10-17' THEN value ELSE 0 END)`  will calculate an average on *all* rows but with value=0 for any rows that aren't 2014-10-17. Try `AVG(CASE WHEN datecolumn = '2014-10-17' THEN value END)` instead, which will ignore rows outside 2014-10-17.

Comment: @SilentCry - also, based on your comment I'm wondering: what is the data type for your `datecolumn` column? Khalid's answer understandably assumes you have a `DATE` type, but if you're getting all zeros (instead of a value that's too low) maybe it's a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP type?

Comment: Same like before, here is code: http://pastebin.com/gfNPqusQ result is: average:57.6667 noRate:3 AverageToday:0.0000 noRatesToday:0

Comment: The TIMESTAMP includes the time, so `datecolumn = 2014-10-17` really means `datecolumn = 2014-10-17 00:00:00.000`, or 2014-10-17 at midnight. To compare just the date part, use `AVG(CASE WHEN DATE(datecolumn) = '2014-10-17' THEN value END)`.

Comment: Also - to make it so the query works for tomorrow and beyond, try `AVG(CASE WHEN DATE(datecolumn) = CURDATE() THEN value END)`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize that I have date in timestamp format. You are my savior, thx :-)